# Zend Framework - How to create an API that is accessible both externally and internally?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm looking to create a web site and will be creating a mobile app at a later date.

I want to be able to offer the same level of data (i.e. a listing of books) to both the web site and the app. I'd like to use an API for this but am struggling to find any examples or decent articles online.

So I suppose my question is, if I were to create a JSON 'endpoint' accessible by a mobile app over HTTP (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/api/v1.0/json) how do access the same functionality internally from my Zend Application?

(obviously I don't want to duplicate the database interaction 'model' steps)

Comment: What did you end up using here? Im in a similar situation right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Zend is really not RESTful, unfortunately, your best bet is JSON-Rpc.

You can do it in a controller, or you can just make an ajax.php in addition to your index.php to reduce overhead like this guy did [here](http://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/05/creating-a-json-rpc-server-with-zend-framework/)

Basically, all you need to do is this:

```
$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$server->setClass('My_Class_With_Public_Methods');
// I've found that a lot of clients only support 2.0
$server->getRequest()->setVersion("2.0");
if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
    $server->setTarget('/ajax.php')
           ->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

    // Grab the SMD
    $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

    // Return the SMD to the client
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $smd;
    return;
}

$server->handle();
```

then somewhere in your layout:

```
$server = new Zend_Json_Server();
$server->setClass('My_Class_With_Public_Methods');
$smd = $server->getServiceMap();
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    rpc = jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({
        url : <?=json_encode($this->baseUrl('/ajax'))?>
        , smd : <?=$smd?>
        , async : true
    });
});
</script>
```

for the sake of example, here's that class:

```
class My_Class_With_Public_Methods {
    /**
      * Be sure to properly phpdoc your methods,
      * the rpc clients like it when you do
      * 
      * @param float $param1
      * @param float $param2
      * @return float
      */
    public function someMethodInThatClass ($param1, $param2) {
        return $param1 + $param2;
    }
}
```

then you can simply call methods like so in javascript:

```
rpc.someMethodInThatClass(first_param, second_param, {
    // if async = true when you setup rpc,
    // then the last param is an object w/ callbacks
    'success' : function(data) {

    }
    'error' : function(data) {

    }
});
```

There aren't a lot of well known JSON-rpc libraries for Android / iPhone - but I have found that this works with Zend_Json_Server for Android:

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html

and this works for iPhone:

http://www.dizzey.com/development/ios/calling-json-rpc-webservice-in-ios/

From here, obviously, you can use My_Class_With_Public_Methods in the same way that javascript / your mobile app does.

Comment: How would I call the someMethodInThatClass method from within the 'index' action of the 'books' controller - for example?

Comment: heh, by calling it? `$myobj = new My_Class_With_Public_Methods(); $myobj->someMethodInThatClass();`

Comment: Thanks Stephen - Wouldn't this end up with the 'Fat Controller' though, e.g. 'My_Class_With_Public_Methods' could be massive? I was thinking I'd need to direct every internal request to the database for data through this controller? Or do I direct those in the normal manner, then 'open up' the data retrieval process by writing the 'My_Class_With_Public_Methods' file and cherry picking the database interactions I want to offer 'publically'?

Comment: I think the penny has dropped. If, in my Zend Library folder I had a '/App/Api/' and then products.php, admin.php, etc.php.... These seperate classes could be used to split up the data requests - thus avoiding a Fat Controller. So an internal request would look like $products = new App_Api_Products();.... $products->listAll(); Externally, an api.php file could be created, passing it the 'products' as the $server->setClass('App_Model_' . $_GET['variable1']...

Comment: Re. 'Fat Controller' - like any MVC enviornment, it certainly could - but doesn't have to. Just like in MVC, you need to make sure that you don't confuse your service / controller layer with your model layer. Much like a controller, your service layer should expose functionality that your models provide - not actually provide that functionality itself.

Comment: I think I understand...... Does my idea of splitting the 'service' layers into seperate files all encompassed in the 'Apit' folder make sense?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. On the same note, would it mean that these group of files that together make the 'api' would have to sit in the '/library/App/Api/' folder? Or could/should they be included in a module within the application itself?

Comment: Well, you typically put controllers in a separate place from libraries, so much so that they often aren't even autoloaded throughout the application, so I'd say separate if you can manage to keep them thin enough.

Comment: So to clarify, you'd put them in a '/application/modules/api/' folder?

Comment: probably just `/application/api`, actually.. but i suppose that's a matter of preference. I don't see a reason for it to be an actual module.. that would be more of a django package approach than a Zend module approach

Comment: I'm struggling to get the application to look in the /application/api folder to load my classes? Any idea how I get the Application to look in that folder? I can autoload from the '/application/models' folder fine for example

Comment: checkout Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, this is more an architecture-related question than a Zend Framework question.

What you are looking for is Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA).

The premise behind SOA is simple, build a single API, and have everything go through it, whether it is internally, or externally. A popular proponent of SOA is Amazon.

In practice, it means that you expose your API exactly as you would use it internally. In OOP, this means that whenever you call your API from an external source (e.g.: a REST API), you'll specify a class name, a method name and a list of arguments, and you'll receive a object in return, just as you would if you'd call it internally.

Per example, you have these:

```
class HelloInstance {
    public $hello;
    public function __construct($hello) { $this->hello = $hello; }
}

class Hello {
    public function getHello() { return new HelloInstance('world'); }
}

class FooInstance {
    public $foo;
    public function __construct($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }
}

class Foo {
    public function getFoo($value) { return new FooInstance($value); }
}
```

If you want to use them internally, you'd do:

```
$hello = new Hello;
$helloInst = $hello->getHello();

$foo = new Foo;
$fooInst = $foo->getFoo('bar');
```

Now you just need a gateway to expose this API externally. Here's a very basic example:

```
include_once 'my_classes.php';

$class = $_GET['class'];
$method = $_GET['method'];

$obj = new $class;
$return = $obj->$method(isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : null);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

You can do the same two calls I demonstrated before, and get the same results, using a REST call:

```
http://my_server/my_gateway.php?class=Hello&method=getHello
http://my_server/my_gateway.php?class=Foo&method=getFoo&value=bar
```

Comment: This is a good answer from an architectural standpoint, but 1. what you describe as REST isn't really RESTful, it's more akin to SOAP. SOAP is all fine and good, but it is decidedly *not* RESTful, and 2. Zend has SOA built in - it's REST server is crap and is not RESTful, but its JSON / XML RPC functionality is right on. Your approach is fine, of course - but it doesn't take advantage of any of Zend's internal SOA. That's not necessarily a bad thing, I suppose, but just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Just curious, how is it not RESTful?

Comment: @StephenJ.Fuhry: Just because you do remote procedure calls doesn't mean it can't be RESTful. Oh and I never said that the above was RESTful by the way. And that's not like SOAP at all.

Comment: @drew010: The only thing required to make the above RESTful is to scrap the query string parameters, and use resources instead, something like: `GET /my_gateway.php/Hello`. I didn't do it because it complicates the example and that wasn't really my point.